# Navigation items are not adding

Tags: swift3, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I am adding two buttons on `UINavigationBar`. I am able to present navigation controller successfully but buttons are not added.

```
let secondVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FilterViewController") as! FilterViewController
        let navigationVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: secondVC)
        navigationVC.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.red
        navigationVC.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "some title"
        navigationVC.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false

        let add = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(dismissFilterView))
        let play = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Play", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(dismissFilterView))

        navigationVC.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [add, play]
        self.present(navigationVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[image]

Comment: NOTE: Next time, crop your screenshot and then upload.

Answer (score 1):

Its not working because you are adding Navigation Items in Navigation Bar. Add in ViewController's Navigation Items.

Replace

```
navigationVC.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [add, play]
```

with

```
secondVC.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [add, play]
```

[image]